# How to show "no records" if filter has no results in material table angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I want to add "No Records Message" If someone search current table is showing empty data!

Below is the link for sample material tables in angular js
   https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples

Comment: data.length = 0 ?

Answer (score 5):

I found the exact solution

In typescript :

```
applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
 filterValue = filterValue.trim(); // Remove whitespace
 filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase(); // MatTableDataSource defaults to lowercase matches
 this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
 if(this.dataSource.filteredData.length==0){
   this.displayNoRecords=true;
 }else{
   this.displayNoRecords=false;

 }
}
```

In Template

```
<mat-card  *ngIf="displayNoRecords" style="padding:100px;">
  <h3 style="text-align:center">We couldn't find data for 
 <span style="color:red">"{{dataSource.filter}}"</span><br>
Make sure the label,type or status are spelled and formatted correctly
</h3>
</mat-card>
```

Answer (score 2):

For people using RXJS the reactive solution is something like this:

Component:

```ts
export class SomeComponent {
  private noResults$ = new Subject<boolean>();

  public applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();

    this.noResults$.next(
      this.dataSource.filteredData.length === 0
    );
  }
}
```

Template:

```html
<mat-card *ngIf="noResults$ | async">
  No results
</mat-card>
```

The `applyFilter` would then most probably also be an observable but to stick to the original I kept it as a function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the the ng-if to check the condition 
`<table ng-if="data==null"  >
<tr > <td colspan="numberofcolum"> No Records </td></tr>
</table>`

Comment: I need in angular 2.x-5.x. Can you please tell me how to implement if user search records and there is no data then I want to display no records similar to datatables.js

Comment: You can use the same way  <table *ngIf="!data"><tr><td>no data </td></tr></table>